# Tomcat8 - Getting image files with accentuation 404 "not found"

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat8

I have the same app in Tomcat 7 and Tomcat 8, on tomcat 7 works perfectly, but in Tomcat8 the image files with accentuations are "not found"

[image]

[image]

real filename: `"FAVORITOS-MENU - SEM SELEÇÃO_e86aff0a5ad040e3b0232a075079dd46.png"`

If i change "`SELE%C7%C3O`" by "`SELEÇÃO`" on link, the image founds... 
Remember this ocours only in tomcat8

Comment: I Solve this, I had to put "URIEncoding="ISO-8859-1"" on conf/server.xml, contrary to what I found in tutorials that spoke to put "UTF-8".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solve this, I had to put "URIEncoding="ISO-8859-1"" on conf/server.xml, contrary to what I found in tutorials that spoke to put "UTF-8".
[image]